# In lua, I want a table`s method to change its value globally, but it only does locally

Tags: lua, love2d

What happens is: I need the self.key to flip between true and false along with a key press.

Apparently, this happens on a local level (if I uncomment the "if" clause, the print happens with the key presses), when what I need is for it to actually change the values of the keys object.

```
keys = {}
keys.escape = false
keys.space  = false

function keys:pressed()
    for key in pairs(self) do
        self.key = love.keyboard.isDown(key)
        --if self.key then print(key) end
    end
end

function love.update()
    keys:pressed()
end
```

Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: `self.key` is *not* the same as `self[key]`! You want the latter. Also keep in mind that the `for` loop will also encounter the `pressed` "key".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem isn't anything to do with that, it's because you are setting the `'key'` index. Not the individual key's index... If that makes any sense.

Basically when you set `self.key`, `key` is a *string*. Not the loop variable. In order to set that you will need to index it with square brackets.

Here's what I mean:

```
keys = {}
keys.escape = false
keys.space  = false

function keys.pressed(self)
    for key in pairs(self) do
        self[key] = love.keyboard.isDown(key)
        --if self.key then print(key) end
    end
end

function love.update()
    keys:pressed()
end
```

This way we use the *variable* `key` instead of the string `'key'`

Comment: OMG, this was a really obvious one lol
Thanks A LOT, worked like a charm :D

Comment: @Vitu No problem, glad I could help.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know I had to accept the answer!
Thanks again!

Comment: @Viti No problem :) (again)